# How do I make the PHP form redirect to another url after successfully submitting the form?

Tags: php

I have read all the previous questions regarding redirecting to another url after a php form is successfully submitted, but I am having trouble doing this myself and would greatly appreciate any help you might be able to give me!

```
<?php 
require_once("included_functions.php");
if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (!empty($_POST['action']))):

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$fictioninterest = $_POST['fictioninterest'];
$bookclub = $_POST['bookclub'];
$newsletter = $_POST['blogtalk'];
$blogtalk = $_POST['blogtalk'];
$skype = $_POST['skype'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$formerrors = false;

if ($name === '') :
    $err_name = '<div class="error">Sorry, your name is a required field</div>';
endif; // input field empty

if ($email === '') :
    $err_email = '<div class="error">Sorry, your email is a required field</div>';
endif; // input field empty

if (isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        $comments = filter_var($_POST['comments'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ); 
}

$formdata = array (
    'name' => $name,
    'email' => $email,
    'fictioninterest' => $fictioninterest,
    'bookclub' => $bookclub,
    'newsletter' => $newsletter,
    'blogtalk' => $blogtalk,
    'skype' => $skype
```

);

```
if (!($formerrors)) :
    $to             =   "bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com";
    $subject    =       "From $name -- Signup Page";
    $message    =       json_encode($formdata);

    $replyto    =       "From: bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com \r\n".
                        "Reply-To: bookclub@literaryfictionreview.com \r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message)):
        $msg = "";
    redirect_to("confirmation.html");
    else:
        $msg = "Problem sending the message";
    endif; // mail form data

endif; // check for form errors

endif; //form submitted
 ?>
```

Do I need to take out the $msg = ""; line? And remove also the $msg line below that returns "Problem sending the message"; ? And I would need to put in a header tag?

Thanks so much for your help with this!

Comment: Add: `header("Location: http://example.com/mypage.php");` inside your if `(mail($to, $subject, $message)):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send an HTTP "location" header (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) via the PHP `header()` function, e.g. `header("Location: /foo.php");`

You'll likely also want to subsequently `exit()` the script so that actions below your `if` conditional don't execute.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. Do I need to take out my $msg lines in the php code above? And then just add in the header function just above the endif;//mail form data line?

Comment: The `location` header should be your server's entire response – don't also send text/html. Therefore, you probably want to store the message in a `$_SESSION` variable and then check for its existence / print it in the successive redirect request.

Comment: Thanks, Charlie. I removed the $msg entirely and simply added in the header function - works perfectly, I REALLY appreciate your help! Thank you!!!